# How create multi constructor by same parameter in Java

Tags: java

How resolve this

how change code to get same result

```
public class myClass
{

   List<Drawable> d;
   List<Bitmap> b;
    public myClass(Integer[] resIDsList)
    {
        ...
    }

    public myClass(List<? extends Drawable> drawableList) // error occure here
    {
        d = drawableList;
    }

    public myClass(List<? extends Bitmap> bitmapList) // and here too
    {
        b = bitmapList;
    }

}
```

if constructors are same in above?

Comment: First of all, I'd say that you should actually have two classes there: the way you construct your class implies it has two different responsibilities, which is not right in terms of design.

Comment: However, on a rare occasion where some constructor logic can accept different lists and still not violate single responsibility principle, one can use factory methods with different names to construct objects.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov three classes: there are 3 constructors there.

Comment: @AndyTurner, depending on what those integers are. Those may be some identifiers by which one can find a set of bitmaps. Although it's usually better to have a find-by-id somewhere outside to reduce coupling of both parts.

Answer (score 5):

Define static factory methods, and make the constructor private:

```
static myClass fromDrawables(List<? extends Drawable> list) {
  return new myClass(list, null);
}

static myClass fromBitmaps(List<? extends Bitmap> list) {
  return new myClass(null, list);
}

private myClass(List<? extends Drawable> drawables, List<? extends Bitmap> bitmaps) {
  // ...
}
```

(You probably want to add another factory method for the `myClass(Integer[])` case; but I hope you get the idea of how to extend the above code for this).

Now you would invoke the factory methods, rather than the constructor:

```
// Not new myClass(...)
myClass a = myClass.fromDrawables(drawablesList);
myClass b = myClass.fromBitmaps(bitmapsList);
```

I'd recommend reading *Effective Java 2nd Ed* Item 1: "Consider static factory methods instead of constructors" for a thorough discussion of this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), this will not compile.  One solution would be to pass the elements to the constructor and simply add them to each respective `List`.

```
public myClass(Drawable... drawables) {
    d = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(drawables));
}

public myClass(Bitmap... bitmaps) {
    b = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(bitmaps));
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't work: there's no `addAll` that accepts an array.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov My bad, it can be viewed as a `List` instead.

Comment: `d = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(drawables))` would be more concise and efficient (it avoids resizing the backing array).

Comment: @AndyTurner Very true, I totally forgot about that constructor.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to change your `List<Drawable> d;` to `List<? extends Drawable> d;` outside of your method. Do this for your `List<Bitmap> b;` as well. Afterwards, your class should look like this:

```
public class myClass
{

  List<? extends Drawable> d;
  List<? extends Bitmap> b;
   public myClass(Integer[] resIDsList)
   {
       ...
   }

   public myClass(List<? extends Drawable> drawableList) // error occurs here
   {
       d = drawableList;
   }

   public myClass(List<? extends Bitmap> bitmapList) // and here too
   {
       b = bitmapList;
   }

}
```

You could also merge both of those constructors into one if you wanted, with this:

```
public myClass(List<? extends Drawable> drawableList, List<? extends Bitmap> bitmapList)
{
   d = drawableList;
   b = bitmapList;
}
```